# iPad - dataWithContentsOfURL throws NSRangeException when I load a URL that has data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

my corporate overlords want me to display image ads for our upcoming iPad application. I'm currently trying to show the image by using the following code:

```
- (UIImage *)getAdImage:(NSString *)adName {

NSString *adID = [self getPrivateConfigSettings:adName];
NSString *adUrl =
     [NSString stringWithFormat:[self getPrivateConfigSettings:@"eplanningURL"],
     [self getPrivateConfigSettings:@"eplanningSite"], adID];

NSData *theData =
     [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:adUrl]];

return [UIImage imageWithData: theData];
}
```

As it stands, its throwing the following exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
'*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (-1( or possibly larger))
beyond bounds (0)'
```

in the line where I create "theData".

However, when I check the URL I'm loading (http://ads.us.e-planning.net/eb/3/9770/19e905cdc35ec591?o=i) it has data on it.

PD: I know that code is leaky! for now I just want to find the cause of my error ;)

Comment: Your code actually isn't leaky. All objects you create are autoreleased (assuming your `-getPrivateConfigSettings:` method follows the normal memory management rules).

Comment: Sorry, are you sure the error is in the NSData creation and not in the NSString *adUrl? Maybe I'm wrong, but your error seems related to a NSArray and not an NSData.

Comment: I assume you checked that 'adUrl' has the correct string?

Comment: I did check adUrl has the correct string, but the problem seems to lie in retreiving the data from the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! it had nothing to do with the URL. As notme points out in his comment, the error clearly isn't related to a NSData but a NSArray.

Turns out, I have this in a separate thread (so I can update the UI while I download the info) and the problem was in the other thread. Misteriously enough, it always crashed when I loaded the 'theData' object. So far I have no idea why the other thread would crash at that particular moment, but since I'm on a tight schedule and my problem is solved I'm just gonna let this one go. Maybe in a later time I'll revisit this and provide a proper explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Try to manually set your URL, like this:

```
- (UIImage *)getAdImage:(NSString *)adName {

NSString *adUrl = @"http://ads.us.e-planning.net/eb/3/9770/19e905cdc35ec591?o=i";

NSData *theData =
     [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:adUrl]];

return [UIImage imageWithData: theData];
}
```

If it works fine, your problem is in retrieving the correct URL from the getPrivateConfigSettings.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. Unfortunately, I tried your suggestion but the problem doesn't seem to lie in retreiving the URL from getPrivateConfigSettings, but in the 'dataWithContentsOfURL' call.